# TRANSLATE() function case sensitivity and precedence issues

Tags: sql-server, translate, case-sensitive

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('NEE', 'Ee', 'Ee')
--NEE
SELECT TRANSLATE('NEE', 'eE', 'eE')
--Nee
SELECT TRANSLATE('NÉE', 'Éé', 'Ee')
--NEE
SELECT TRANSLATE('NÉE', 'éÉ', 'eE')
--NeE
```

How do you prevent a match by a differently cased character ? In the above examples, output with lower case character were not what I expected.

Comment: use case sensitive collation for the strings?

Comment: SELECT TRANSLATE('NEE' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'eE' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'eE' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS) works as expected and returns 'NEE'

Comment: @siggemannen: if you want to propose your answer I will confirm it. Thx to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For case-sensitive function calls, easiest is to use a case sensitive collation.

Testscript:

```sql
SELECT  TRANSLATE('NEE', 'Ee', 'Ee')
,   TRANSLATE('NEE', 'eE', 'eE')
,   TRANSLATE('NÉE', 'Éé', 'Ee')
,   TRANSLATE('NÉE', 'éÉ', 'eE')
,   TRANSLATE('NEE', 'Ee' collate latin1_general_cs_as, 'Ee' collate latin1_general_cs_as)
,   TRANSLATE('NEE', 'eE' collate latin1_general_cs_as, 'eE' collate latin1_general_cs_as)
,   TRANSLATE('NÉE', 'Éé' collate latin1_general_cs_as, 'Ee' collate latin1_general_cs_as)
,   TRANSLATE('NÉE', 'éÉ' collate latin1_general_cs_as, 'eE' collate latin1_general_cs_as)
```

Outputs:

| (column 1) | (column 2) | (column 3) | (column 4) | (column 5) | (column 6) | (column 7) | (column 8) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NEE | Nee | NEE | NeE | NEE | NEE | NEE | NEE |